# Adding new view/phtml file in Zend Framework2

Tags: php, zend-framework, view, zend-framework2, structure

I would like to add a new phtml file to my index folder in which I already have several views:

```
index
landing
```

And so on... I access them by using the following logic:

```
sitename.com/index/landing
```

or

```
sitename.com/index/index
```

How can I add the phtml file (my new view) to my index folder so that I'm able to see it when I enter in the browser:

```
sitename.com/index/mynewview
```

I'm quite new to the whole Zend Framework, and I'm not sure how the structure works exactly, so I'd like to find out more. Can you guys help me out with this, how am I supposed to do this?

Thanks heaps! :)

P.S. The views are in the following directory structure:

```
module/application/view/application/index/
```

and then here are all of the views, this is where I'd like to add my new view and access it from browser like this:

```
/index/testview
```

Edit:

When I add the testview.phtml to the index  directory and put some test tags like this in it:

```
<h1> Testing new view page </h1>
```

It's not being rendered on the browser

Comment: Please learn at least basics. It is an MVC framework. Views are not invoked directly, but via controller. The file structure is described here http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/modules.html

Comment: @AlexBlex  Can you reply in a form of answer so that I can at least accept ur answer to thank you for the effort?

Comment: I'd suggest to remove the question to avoid downvotes: *This question does not show any research effort...etc*

Comment: @Saeven gives you the answer you are looking for. I'd suggest you look into it. You need to setup/configure routing and map your route to a controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is an MVC framework, you're skipping a few steps.  You're probably going to get a few harsh responses, but I'll try to fill in the holes for you very quickly.

*Ignore the file folder structure for a minute.*

This is a route:

```
/index/landing
```

Routes point to `Actions` inside of `Controllers` to work.

Assuming you have started with the skeleton, open up your module's module.config.php, you should see route config, e.g.:
https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L29

You'll need to add a config entry for the routes you want to serve.  It could be as simple as a `Literal` entry for /index/landing, or something more complex (Segments, Regex, etc.) that handle patterns for routing.  Spend some time tinkering and learning here; routes are pretty critical to working with MVC.

When configuring the route, the assumption is that you have a Controller set up, and that this Controller has an Action (to which your route is pointed).  That Action, is where you can connect template files (phtml,twig,etc.) to routes:

```
// dummy action that serves index/testview
public function fooAction(){
    $vm = new Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
    $vm->setTemplate('index/testview');
    return $vm;
}
```

That index/testview, will be in your module's view templates, not in your public folder.

I think that's a reasonable primer to get you on your way!

Take some time to learn:
http://zf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#userguide

Maybe start here:
http://zf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/in-depth-guide/understanding-routing.html

ZF2 (V3 is coming!) is a beautiful thing, it's worth it.

Good luck.